# Getting error to install Meteor in WebStorm

Tags: meteor, npm, webstorm, bcrypt

```
Meteor 1.4.1 is available. Update this project with 'meteor update'.
=> Started MongoDB.
=> Errors prevented startup:

   While downloading npm-bcrypt@0.8.7...:
   error: Command failed: C:\Users\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.4.0-1\mt-os.windows.x86_32\dev_bundle\bin\npm.cmd rebuild --no-bin-links --update-binary
   gyp ERR! build error
   gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\msbuild.exe` failed with exit code: 1
   gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit
   (C:\Users\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.4.0-1\mt-os.windows.x86_32\dev_bundle\lib\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:276:23)
   gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
   gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
   gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:200:12)
   gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
```

Answer (score 0):

The following steps should solve it.

1. Remove accounts-password package
2. Add npm-bcrypt package `meteor add npm-bcrypt`
3. Add accounts-password package

If this doesn't work try installing MS Build Tools [Download Here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48159)